# Pages loading twice

Tags: sockets, loading, mirc

I'm using mIRC to open a socket to a website. The logs from the DB show that the page is opening at LEAST 2 times, sometimes 3. The 2nd time is usually 2 minutes from the first time. However, the socket is only opening once; I have an echo on sockopen. I manually went through firefox and clicked on the link, the same thing happened that happened within the mIRC script.

This doesn't happen to anyone else on this site; does anyone have any theories as to why the page is loading twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an internet connection issue in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Since pure sockets never interpret any HTTP-codes, it must reside within your code...
And since you didn't supply any code paste, there is nearly no way to help you.

The only thing I can think of would be some sort of timer or event which causes the sockets to close and/or reopened again.
This would explain the page loading twice.
But if you trigger the sockopen yourself with /sockopen or via an alias there must be some cause in your script or other scripts which interference with it.

You should paste your code on http://pastebin.com/ and paste the link her

Comment: I stated that it was having the same error when opening the website manually through the web browser, therefore it is not the code of the mIRC script. I also stated that the error does not happen for anyone else on other networks, so it is not the PHP script. It must be a network issue or something.

Comment: It's no argument that it reloads when you use your browser because your browser interprets HTTP-codes like redirects. AND follows them automaticly.

Comment: It doesn't reload, it randomly has data coming in 2 minutes later without a refresh or any javascript posting etc

Comment: So the socket stays open after the request? Normally the webserver closes the socket after sending all its content. That is commonly used to display the 'loading'-cycle in browsers (as long as the socket stays open). Maybe you should still paste your code for detailed help.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I forgot about this thread.

The problem is, the same issue occurs while they manually open the webpage through a browser. And it happens for NOONE else.